# How do I re-apply an ignore pattern?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have added an extension to the svn:ignore property of a folder and have had it applied to all subfolders.

But the files with that extension are still in version control. How do I force the re-application of ignore rules so that those files are unversionned accordingly ?

Comment: Just like in git, and without the possibility of rewriting history to not add the files in history, I _think_ (not an svn master over here so take my word with a grain of salt) you will have to remove them from the branch so that the files are ignored _moving forward_.